# R loop cannot open file connection

Tags: json, r, web-scraping, httr

I'm using a loop to retrieve data from an api, parse them into json files and save each json file in its own directory. The problem is when I run the loop I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>   cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In dir.create(file) :
>   cannot create dir '~\sample', reason 'No such file or directory'
> 2: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
>     cannot open file '~/sample': No such file or directory
> ```

I can run the whole process without a loop and it works fine and I know I have permission to write drive. I've tried it with both a network drive and my local C:\ user directory and receive the same error.

Unfortunately, I can't give an entirely reproducible example since I'm working with a personal developer token for the website but here's the loop I'm trying to use:

```
require(RCurl)
require (httr)
require(plyr)
require(rjson)

cvfe <- character.vector.of.file.extensions

for(i in length(cvfe)){
  test[i] <- paste("https://api.sample.com", cvfe[i],  sep = "")

  data.16 <- GET(test[i], add_headers(Accept = "application/json",  Authorization = "Token"))

  data.16.lst <- (content(data.2016, "parsed"))
  data.16.df <- ldply(data.16.lst[[3]], data.frame)
  data.16 <- toJSON(data.16.df)

  file = paste("~/sample", cvfe[i], sep = "")
  dir.create(file)
  write(data.16, file = file)
}
```

Can anyone explain this doesn't work? Is it my loop or is there an issue with the security settings on my machine or something else entirely?

Windows 10,
R version 3.2.3

Comment: You probably want `"./sample"`.

Comment: Thanks but "~/sample" is just meant to be a place holder for the full file directory I'm trying to save to. Apologies if my notation is unclear.

Comment: You're unlikely to get very useful advice unless you provide a reproducible example.